# Proving $\sqrt{\int_a^bf^2(x)\sin x\;dx}+\sqrt{\int_a^bf^2(x)\cos x\;dx}\le(b-a)\int_a^bf^2(x)dx$ using Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I need to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\left|\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right).g\left(x\right)dx\right|\le \sqrt{\int _a^b\:f^2\left(x\right)dx}\cdot \sqrt{\int _a^b\:g^2\left(x\right)dx}
$$
to prove this:
$$
\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin\left(x\right)dx\right)^2+\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)dx\right)^2\le \left(b-a\right)\int _a^b\:f^2\left(x\right)dx
$$

So, I know that I need to manipulate the left side to get into the right side of the equation. I already get that the (b-a) part comes from $$ \int _a^bdx$$ and the rest of the right side is the same, except for the sin and cos.

In this way, I "have to disappear" with the sin and cos. I also noticed that the inequality of calchy is a product and in my case I have a sum. I know that we have the trigonometric identity $$sin^2\left(x\right)+cos^2\left(x\right)=1$$ applying it I would disappear with the sine and cosine, but I still continue with a sum.

Am I thinking right? I'm a little confused in this part of manipulation. Does it make sense what I'm talking about? Any tips that can help me?

---

**Uptade:**

I had written the wrong equation, sorry about that. So, I redid the correct one and it was as follows:
$$
\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin\left(x\right)dx\right)^2+\left(\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)dx\right)^2\le \left(b-a\right)\int _a^b\:f^2\left(x\right)dx
$$

Taking g(x) = sin(x) and h(x) = cos(x), following Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I have:
$$
\int _a^b\:\left|sin\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)\right|dx\le \sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin^2\left(x\right)dx}\cdot \sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)dx}
$$

$$
f\left(x\right)\cdot \left(\int _a^b\:\left|sin^2\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)\right|\right)dx\le f\left(x\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin\left(x\right)dx}\cdot \:\sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)dx}\right)
$$
$$
\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^2\cdot \left(\int _a^b\:\left|sin^2\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)\right|dx\right)^2\le f\left(x\right)^2\cdot \left(\sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin\left(x\right)dx}\cdot \:\sqrt{\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)dx}\right)^2
$$
$$
f^2\left(x\right)\cdot \int _a^b\:sin^2\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)dx^{ }\le f^2\left(x\right)^{ }\cdot \int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)sin^2\left(x\right)dx\cdot \:\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)cos^2\left(x\right)dx
$$

And I stop it there, don't know what can I do from here. Any tips?

Comment: Why would $$ \sqrt{\int_a^b f(x)^2\sin(x)dx} $$ make sense ? the integral could be negative, isn't it $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$?

Comment: @Tuvasbien you were right, I've got the wrong equation, I updated with the correct one. Can you saw it, again? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Put $g(x)=\sin x$ in your definition of C-S. Square it (thinking carefully about) the signs as you do. Do the same with $g(x)=\cos x$. Add the two inequalities. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$ \left(\int_a^b f(x)\cos(x)dx\right)^2\leqslant\left(\int_a^b f(x)^2dx\right)\left(\int_a^b \cos^2(x)dx\right) $$
and samely
$$ \left(\int_a^b f(x)\sin(x)dx\right)^2\leqslant\left(\int_a^b f(x)^2dx\right)\left(\int_a^b \sin^2(x)dx\right) $$
Therefore, summing these inequalities gives that the LHS is less than
$$ \left(\int_a^b f(x)^2dx\right)\left(\int_a^b \cos^2(x)dx+\int_a^b \sin^2(x)dx\right)=(b-a)\int_a^b f(x)^2dx $$
since $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$.